# search outlook addressbook using AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, outlook

Is it possible to query outlook address book using AS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AIR and If you know VB.Net or C# you will be able to create a console app which accesses the Outlook application model (including the contacts database) Air can then connect to it using NativeProcess.

[Have a look at this](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5850937.html) for info on connecting to Outlook on the .Net side...

and [this on the NativeProcess side](http://mchristoff.com/2009/12/using-the-air-2-0-nativeprocess-api-to-control-mplayer/)

As part of your installation, you will need to provide this outlook interfacing console app to your end users.

Answer (score 2):

if you know C++ you could write a command-line application that extracts data from the outlook contacts list, and use the AIR NativeProcess class to import the data into flash. It does mean that you have to use AIR though; it will have to install as a desktop application before it will work.

Comment: If you know VB.Net or C# you will be able to do this too.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Even using AIR/desktop applications, you wouldn't have access to a non-app-specific file on the filesystem unless you prompted the user to browse for it.